# How to conditionaly check an hour difference between two dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date with hours and minutes like 2/3/2019 10:30 am , and I do the following to find the diffence in hours which I already formatted like ( h )

```
=now() - date
```

I want to check if the difference is more than 12 ( where I mean 12 hours) to do something.

if(actual difference>12; "hello"; "bye")

But is not checking the actual difference but the serial difference

How can I check the actual difference in hours?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as numbers where the integer part is the number of days since 1899-12-31. The fractional part measures the time within a day. So, `24 * (now() - date)` will give you the number of hours elapsed.

NB: the formatting is only a question of display and won't influence what's done by the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check conditionaly the difference in the hours unit between two times we can do if(hour(actual difference)>12; "hello"; "bye")

We put the function hour() as noted in

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6